# How to allow each user rate once time only in Firebase rating system

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following is the rating system in my android app for each hike trail. User can rate for every trail and display the average rating in real-time. But now the problem is each user can rate for multiple times for each trail. I want to let the user only rate  each trail for once time only . Do i need to change the Firebase data structure or I can rewrite the code as follow in order to make this happen? Thank you:)

```
public class XXXAcitvity extends AppCompatActivity implements RatingDialogListener {

public String trailId="";
public FloatingActionButton rateButton;
public RatingBar ratingBar;

FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
DatabaseReference trails;
DatabaseReference ratings;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.XXX);

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    rateButton=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.ratingbtn) ;
    ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingbar);

    //Firebase
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    trails = mDatabase.getReference("Trails");
    ratings = mDatabase.getReference("Ratings");

    //get intent

    if(getIntent()!=null)
    {
        trailId=getIntent().getStringExtra("TrailID");

    }

    if(!trailId.isEmpty())
    {

        getRatingTrail(trailId);

    }
```

when click the rating button, firebase will automatically generate random key for each rate and set the value according to the rating class model, and trailId is the key for pointing both Ratings child and Trails child in Firebase

```
    @Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int value, String comment) {
    //
     final Rating rating = new Rating(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(),
             trailId,
            String.valueOf(value),
            comment);

     ratings.push().setValue(rating)
             .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                 }
             });

@Override
public void onNegativeButtonClicked() {

}
}
```

Here is the function calculate the average rating in firebase

```
private void getRatingTrail(String trailId)
{
    Query trailRating = 
 ratings.orderByChild("trailId").equalTo(trailId);


    trailRating.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       int count=0;
       int sum=0;
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                Rating item = postSnapshot.getValue(Rating.class);
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(item.getRateValue());
                count++;

            }

            if(count!=0)
            {
                int average= sum/count;
                ratingBar.setRating(average);
            }




        }
```

Rating class

```
public class Rating {
  private String UserID;
  private String trailId;
  private String rateValue;
  private String comment;

  public Rating(){

  }

public Rating(String UserID, String trailId, String rateValue, String comment) {
    this.UserID = UserID;
    this.trailId = trailId;
    this.rateValue = rateValue;
    this.comment = comment;
}

public void setUserID(String UserID) {
    UserID = UserID;
}

public void setTrailId(String trailId) {
    trailId = trailId;
}

public void rateValue(String rateVaule) {
    this.rateValue = rateVaule;
}

public void setCommennht(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getUserID() {
    return UserID;
}

public String getTrailId() {
    return trailId;
}

public String getRateValue() {
    return rateValue;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}
```

}

Here is my database structure

```
"Ratings" : {
"-L8qMG4cttR7VIYMrhNS" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "1",
  "trailId" : "Trail1",
  "userID" : "bNgsbQKk7rcb755ISW6oDo7EUaJ3"
},
"-L8qMLRyC5TV2kULIMm2" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "1",
  "trailId" : "Trail2",
  "userID" : "bNgsbQKk7rcb755ISW6oDo7EUaJ3"
},
"-L8qMOdE1QylSX8smLb7" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "5",
  "trailId" : "Trail2",
  "userID" : "bNgsbQKk7rcb755ISW6oDo7EUaJ3"
},
"-L8qMQjjTCqqCBJ5dbFe" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "5",
  "trailId" : "Trail2",
  "userID" : "bNgsbQKk7rcb755ISW6oDo7EUaJ3"
},

"-L8qN3RZTPWXy3cWSf2h" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "1",
  "trailId" : "Trail2",
  "userID" : "oWrUNCA7P8QJlzG1sZ6sHwEcBfu1"
},
"-L8qN8LNzIZNMwu0EGwE" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "5",
  "trailId" : "Trail2",
  "userID" : "oWrUNCA7P8QJlzG1sZ6sHwEcBfu1"
},
"-L8qNEWQ7GSFPpxJMA9A" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "5",
  "trailId" : "Trail3",
  "userID" : "oWrUNCA7P8QJlzG1sZ6sHwEcBfu1"
},
"-L8qNP_e45GaJj4EnmKV" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "1",
  "trailId" : "Trail3",
  "userID" : "kK2ERTyxUgRo4cvrG8gOsN8tRge2"
},
"-L8qNUtkWJjqHlVkFOZy" : {
  "comment" : "",
  "rateValue" : "1",
  "trailId" : "Trail3",
  "userID" : "kK2ERTyxUgRo4cvrG8gOsN8tRge2"
}
```

},

```
"Trails" : {
  "Trail1" : {
  "TimeDuration" : "60mins",
  "dec" : "the most pretty trails",
  "distance" : "20km",
  "name" : "Dragon Backs",
  "trailId" : "Trail1"
},
"Trail2" : {
  "name" : "Hike 2",
  "trailId" : "Trail2"
},
"Trail3" : {
  "name" : "Hike 3",
  "trailId" : "Trail3"
}
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you have to check if the user has already rate the Trail, with your database structure, you have to check all the Rating table, and see if the userId and the name of the trail he has voted is in the list. However this is very inefficient.

What I suggest is to create a new table users-trails, where you store all the trails rated by the users.

For example for the user: bNgsbQKk7rcb755ISW6oDo7EUaJ3

```
"users-trails" : {
 "-bNgsbQKk7rcb755ISW6oDo7EUaJ3" : {
   Trail1: 1
   Trail2: 1
},
```

Then when you want to see if the user has already rate the Trail1, you just need to do a quick check in this table.

The code to add the data to this table, is simple:

```
FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference userTrailsDB = mDatabase.getReference("user-trails");

userTrailsDB.child(userID).child(trailId).setValue(1);
```

And to get the information, is not very complicate as well:

```
userTrailsDB.child(userID).child(trialId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               //Do Whatever if exits
            } 


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        };
```

Comment: Where should i put `userTrailsDB.child(userID).child(trailId).setValue(1);` because i also need to check whether the user rate the trail before set the value in to this userTrailsDB

Comment: You should call it when you add something into the table rating. So every time you add a value to the table rating , add also a value to this table.